# Instantiating the bound controller with values while unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test-drive a controller which is bound to a directive.

```
app.module('App')
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '../my-directive.html',
        scope: true,
        bindToController: {
            model: '='
        },
        controller: 'DirectiveCtrl as DirectiveCtrl'
    };
})
.controller('DirectiveCtrl', function() {
    var DirectiveCtrl = this,
        model = DirectiveCtrl.model;

    DirectiveCtrl.resetValue = function() {
        DirectiveCtrl.model = model;
    };
});
```

In the test,

```
describe('DirectiveCtrl', function() {
    var DirectiveCtrl,
        model = {
            id: 'id',
            name: 'name'
        };

    beforeEach(module('App'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        DirectiveCtrl = $controller('DirectiveCtrl');
        // code to initialize controller with model value;
    }));

    it('resets the default value', function() {
        DirectiveCtrl.resetValue();
        expect(DirectiveCtrl.model).toEqual(model);
    });
});
```

I want to initialize the controller in a similar way to how a bounded controller would behave during directive compilation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution in angular [$controller decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller). The second argument takes an object with bound values.

So the test would be,

```
describe('DirectiveCtrl', function() {
  var DirectiveCtrl,
    model = {
        id: 'id',
        name: 'name'
    };

  beforeEach(module('App'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    DirectiveCtrl = $controller('DirectiveCtrl', {
        model: model
    });
  }));

  it('resets the default value', function() {
    DirectiveCtrl.resetValue();
    expect(DirectiveCtrl.model).toEqual(model);
  });
});
```